What are the opportunities after studying Bachelor of Philosophy?
I am currently studying Bachelor of Philosophy. I want to know what are the career options I have available. I am aiming for a Masters and PhD.

There are only a tiny number of jobs where a having a PhD in philosophy will help you get hired.  It's not a good way to make money.

Well, what do previous graduates from your program do? With or without an advanced degree?

If you’re not financially constrained, any advanced degree of interest to you might be worth pursuing. If, on the other hand, you’ll need to earn your bread by the sweat of your brow, your philosophical studies might better occupy your weekends and after hours.

This really depends on what the culture of your country is.  In the US, the vast majority of college graduates work in jobs that have very little to do with their major.

What happens after your degree is usually outside academia, and hence outside the scope of this SE.  Voting to close.

Search your local jobs portal.
